# What is the difference between $ sudo reboot and $ reboot?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, operating-systems, noobs

I have got Raspberry Pi 2 Model B v1.1 with NOOBS v1.4.2 Raspbian loaded.

What is the difference between

```
$ sudo reboot
```

and

```
$ reboot
```

typing in terminal?

Comment: sudo runs the command as root, if reboot without sudo works it is because it was setup in /etc/sudoers for your user to use without entering a password. In the end the same command is being run.

Answer (score 3):

Adding `sudo` before a command runs the command as if you were the user `root`. Some commands require to be run as `root` because it is the highest user by default. When you run `sudo reboot` you are running `reboot` from `root`. If you just type `reboot` you are running `reboot` from your current user, which may not have the necessary permissions to enter system commands like that.